# access RDS through ec2 beanstalk instance

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance running and I want to access it from a beanstalk instance. They are both in the same VPC and I have followed the instructions from the amazon documentation [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario1).

Here is my table for the inbound rules I have assigned to the security group of the RDS instance.

[image: inbound rules for rds security group]

The sg-c6...etc is the security group of the beanstalk instance.
When I am trying to run

```
 mysql -u master -ppass -h rds.instanceid.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com dbname
```

I am getting

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rds.instance.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
```

Comment: is your VPC open to internet connections? did you check your VPC subnets routing? cross subnet access is allowed?

Comment: I haven't made any other settings. But they are both in the same vpc and I can access the beanstalk instance from the outside! I am sorry if I dont get  your suggestions but I am pretty new in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you have an issue with networking restrictions within your VPC. 
Please try to login to your AWS account and navigate to the [VPC](https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/) management section. Navigate to Route Table and select your route table. Edit your Subnet Associations and make sure that all subnets are included

Comment: thank you! you just saved my day! I just needed to add the sub nets in the route tables

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL server will run on port 3306 but your security group says 3310.  MySQL on RDS will be no different.  I would suggest changing the security group port to 3306.

Comment: I have setup the DB using this port. and when I am connecting from MySQL workbench I am using 3310 and connects without any issues